# AWS Redshift Geometry data type

Tags: amazon-web-services, geometry, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, spatial

I am trying to insert geometry data from RDS(postgres) into AWS Redshift using `INSERT INTO {redshift table} SELECT id, geom, ... from {RDS table}.

This throws an error for me.
ERROR: Value of Geometry type is invalid.len= Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Value of Geometry type is invalid.len= code: 25301 context: 1261630 max=1048447 query: 4488383 location: federation_fetchers.cpp:262 process: query13_502_4488383 [pid=18868] -----------------------------------------------

I know Redshift support `Geometry` data types, but there is a limit to what it supports. Thats what  I understand from the error.
Did anyone have any success with complex geometry data types with Redshift?

I am expecting to insert any complex geometry data type into redshift